# "type": "module" set in package.json but still get the "set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension." error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, toast-ui-editor

I'm trying to get a TOAST UI app working without success. I've followed the instruction [here](https://github.com/nhn/tui.editor/blob/master/docs/en/getting-started.md). When I 'npm start' I am getting this error 'Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.'

I have set the "type": "module" in the package.json file and in the src tag of the html component and renamed the my app.js to app.mjs without success.

Not sure what I'm missing?! Thanks!

package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "my-toastie",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.mjs",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.mjs"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@toast-ui/editor": "^3.2.2"
  }
}
```

app.mjs looks like this:

```
import Editor from "@toast-ui/editor";
//import "@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor.css"; // Editor's Style

const editor = new Editor({
  el: document.querySelector("#editor"),
  height: "600px",
  initialEditType: "markdown",
  previewStyle: "vertical",
});
```

index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Hello World Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="editor"></div>

    <script type="module" src="app.mjs"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The exact error I get when I run `npm start` is:

> my-toastie@1.0.0 start
> node app.mjs

(node:50800) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/xxxxx/Documents/personal projects/my-toastie/node_modules/@toast-ui/editor/dist/esm/index.js:8
import { Fragment, Schema, Slice, NodeRange, Mark as Mark$1, DOMParser, Node as Node$3 } from 'prosemirror-model';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

Comment: I'm confused.  The error you list in your question is something that comes from nodejs, but the code you show appears to be code that runs in the browser.  In addition, you say you show `app.mjs`, but the HTML file refers to `app.js` so these don't match up.  In addition the package.json has no `type: "module"` in it.  I can't tell if you're just not showing us the actual nodejs code that generates that error or if you're attempting to run nodejs code in a browser or what is actually going on here?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I've updated the package.json part to show the correct  contents and I've updated the index.html to reference the app.mjs. Changing the reference in the index.html still gives the same error. In terms of where I am running it, I am not sure, I am a bit of a noob at this. I assume I fire up a virtual server with npm start, not sure if that is running the js file server or client side.

Comment: So, the code you show all looks like code that runs in the browser and is not the source of that error.  That error comes from nodejs, not from the browser.  Are you running code in nodejs?  If so, please show that code and how you run that code.

Comment: I guess I must be running in nodejs as I'm using the 'npm start' command?

Comment: So, when you run `npm start`, EXACTLY what error do you get, word for word?  Please copy the precise error into your question.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll add it to the question as it is long and there for others to see.

Comment: I was not familiar with toastUI but when I look at its doc, it looks like an entirely client-side library, meant to only loaded and run in the browser.  If that's the case, you should not be trying to run this in nodejs at all.  You will note that the error seems to be coming from `/Users/xxxxx/Documents/personal projects/my-toastie/node_modules/@toast-ui/editor/dist/esm/index.js` which is deep inside of the library itself, not your code.  I suspect that's because this is not nodejs code - it's browser code.

Comment: That's great intel thank you. how would I run it as browser code? Would Live Server run it as browser code? I get this error with Live Server 
index.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@toast-ui/editor". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: I assumed that the ES6 modules commands in the doc would be run by node

Comment: Well like I said, I don't have any experience with that library, but you can see [here](https://github.com/nhn/tui.editor/tree/master/apps/editor#via-contents-delivery-network-cdn) how to include it in a browser page with a `<script>` tag when referencing it from a CDN.  Otherwise, you'd have to put toastui into your server project and create a route on the server that would serve the toastui-editor script and referencing that route in your browser page.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @jfriend00 I was able to get it working with the assistance you provided! I'll share the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was mixing up client and server side libraries. I got it working with this client side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>my toastie</title>
    <!-- Editor's Style -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://uicdn.toast.com/editor/latest/toastui-editor.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/editor/latest/toastui-editor-all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const Editor = toastui.Editor;
    </script>
    <script>
      const editor = new Editor({
        el: document.querySelector("#editor"),
        height: "600px",
        initialEditType: "markdown",
        previewStyle: "vertical",
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```